# Get google api data group by date

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-analytics-api, google-api-js-client

I used gapi.class.php version 3 to take number of visitors, But I get only total number. I want to get analytics data group by date.

Here are access url to google

```
https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/ga?ids=ga:xxxxx&dimensions=ga:browser,ga:browserVersion,ga:month&metrics=ga:pageviews,ga:visits,ga:sessions&sort=ga:pageviews,ga:visits,ga:sessions&start-date=2016-10-01&end-date=2017-01-13&start-index=1&max-results=10000
```

Here are php code

```html
$fromDate = '2016-10-01';
$toDate  =  '2017-01-30';
$ga->requestReportData(xxxxxx,array('browser','browserVersion','month'),array('pageviews','visits','sessions'), $sort_metric=null, $filter=null, $start_date=$fromDate, $end_date=$toDate, $start_index=1, $max_results=10000);
$visits = array('visits'=>$ga->getVisits());
echo json_encode($visits);
```

Json return is

```
  {"visits":1399313}
```

Please, how do I get its data by month

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried following this https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/quickstart/web-js  I am not enough of a JavaScript developer to be able to help more then to say the data is probably there in the $ga variable.

Comment: Yes @DaImTo, I did.

Comment: You have to add dimension `ga:date`

Comment: Do you mean to add 'date' value to second array. I did it but still the same result @dikesh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After couple of hours I found solution.
I remove browser and browserVersion
it is need only month and year.
Jason return by group of date and year Thank you all